# What does "to put a bit of stick about" mean?

Tags: idioms, british-english, politics

I have heard this phrase in the *House of Cards* (1990`s) TV series, and Google does not lead to any good explanation.

To my mind, the main character is using this phrase when he intends to make the things go as he wants to.

Comment: *About* is used to indicate movement in British English. *Stick* seems to mean a threat of punishment (contrast it with carrot) or unwelcome measures. If someone moves a stick around your head or body, you will get scared and do whatever he wants or orders you to do.

Comment: My pleasure. Please make sure you include some context (more sentences before and after the phrase) and your own research efforts when you ask another question. Please read the link. http://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: I wonder if it is related to the practise in the British Army of Officers and NCOs carrying Pace and Swagger sticks as symbols of office?https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pace_stick. Originally they were also used to strike lower ranks when giving orders if not followed quickly enough. A man like Urquhart would have thought of himself as similar to the officer class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means to make a display or threat of violence usually to maintain discipline or keep people cowed and submissive.

Comment: Please [edit] to add citations to reliable sources that support the assertions made here. Unsourced material may be disputed or [deleted](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers).

Answer (score -1):

It is an idiomatic expression close in meaning to "[throw a spanner in the works](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/put-throw-a-spanner-in-the-works)". The idea is that of influencing  or manipulating   someone or something to your one's own advantage,

> - to do something that prevents a plan or activity from succeeding.

Cambridge  Dictionary

> - [The Whips Office](https://www.totalpolitics.com/articles/news/waning-power-whips) is probably the most mysterious and intriguing office in Westminster - the place where secrets are kept and bodies buried. There are dozens of idioms attached to it - ‘A meeting without coffee’, ‘***Put a bit of stick about***’, ‘the black book’ or ‘you might well think that, I couldn’t possibly comment’.

From (www.totalpolitics.com)

Comment: @Hoborg *to throw a spanner in the works* is not close in meaning to *put a bit of stick about*